# Is it possible to connect PSVR to unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, virtual-reality

I have a question i'm making a vr game in unreal engine but i only have a PSVR so is it possible for me to connect the PSVR to my PC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident in saying that PSVR is propriatary to sony and would not work juste like plugging it to your PC. (pretty much like a ps4 controller where you need a third party software to emulate it as an Xbox controller)

Eventually if you have a dev kit or something but I assure that.

Comment: I found that there's a software called trinusPSVR that gives you a way to play games on steam with PSVR but i dont know if you can connect it with unreal engine.

Comment: So do you know about a third party software that can be used for this?

Comment: I don't know any third party app for PSVR (i only use ds4 for ps4 controllers) but i think trinusPSVR is your best bet as it seems to be a third party for PSVR

Comment: Yeah i know but i didn't find a way to connect the trinusPSVR to unreal engine

Comment: ok I'll see what I can find but I would say it's pretty much a lost cause if this kind of third party software can't make it work

Comment: I don't think so it's really just a software that let's you map a ps4 controller to make windows thinks he deals with an xbox controller

Comment: So is it possible to connect motion controller with ds4 to the pc?